# Convert Javascript date to java date

Tags: javascript, java, date, timezone

I want to pass the date from front-end to backend and then save to database.
For front end- I am using javascript and jQuery
for backend springboot, java8.
When  I am creating a date of this year in JavaScript

```
let setDate = new Date(2022, 11, 31);
console.log(setDate);
```

I get the output it like : `Sat Dec 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

In javascript:

```
reqObj.setDate = setDate;
```

the object in Java for this is `String setDate`
But when it comes to backend  spring boot controller it becomes:
`2022-01-30T18:30:00.000Z` (day is decreased by one/ timezone changes from IST to GMT) (datatype is String in java)
After getting the String I make some formatting changes as per my need:

```
private String getDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String resultsDate = "";
    try {
        resultsDate = sdf1.format(sdf.parse(date));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getName(), ".getDate() Exception : {}" + e);
    }
    return resultsDate;
}
```

Timezone changes resulting in date change, but the date should be the same i.e. like (`2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z`)
How can I solve it from the front end?

Comment: _day is decreased by one_. No it is converted from IST (Indian Standard Time) to UTC and 5 and half hours is reduced

Comment: Yes, how can I avoid that?

Comment: you need to check how you are sending your date to server and how it is saved?

Comment: You haven't told us how you're sending the JavaScript date to the server. You can't send `Date` objects, so you'll be sending something else. It could be the `Date`'s milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value (which by its nature is in UTC), or it could be a string of some kind, with or without timezone information. We can't help you without knowing what you're sending. *"I am not concerned about the timezone"* - That's probably a mistake. Instead, care about the timezone, and if you want to treat things as being independent of timezones, use UTC consistently throughout.

Comment: I am sending the date as String to the backend

Comment: What format of string? With or without timezone information? How are you converting that string into a Java `Date`? (Why are you using Java's `Date` at all? In modern code, something from [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is best practice.)

Comment: Question updated

Comment: but `00:00:00 GMT+0530` is not same time as `00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: anyway try `sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));` but I would also strongly recommend `java.time` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543763/convert-javascript-date-to-java-date#comment117636064_66543763) by T.J.Crowder

Comment: The date is the same. As in: the point in time is the same. It is only printed differently. No, I don’t think you can easily avoid it being the same. :-) You can probably mimic the printing if it’s important to you.

Comment: I recommend that in Java you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, on the server side you need the calendar date, 2022-12-31 in your example. Neither the time of day nor the time zone.

What you are getting in Spring, `2022-01-30T18:30:00.000Z`, is a point in time. The correct point in time by the way, but if I am correct that you didn’t need a point in time, then this is not very useful. It’s only a little bit of guesswork on my part: Your browser knows your time zone setting, India Standard Time, and therefore does two things based on it: (1) It constructs a JavaScript `Date` representing the start of day in your time zone. (2) It prints the point in time represented by the JavaScript `Date` in your time zone. The browser further assumes that the server does not know the client time zone, and it therefore converts the point in time to UTC, which gives `2022-01-30T18:30:00.000Z`. The trailing `Z` is pronounced Zulu and means UTC.

So I suppose that what you need to do is to persuade the JavaScript code in your client to send the date without time of day and without time zone. Since I neither know your JavaScript code nor very much JavaScript at all, and cannot tell you the details here.

**Use java.time.** As a slight aside, I recommend that in Java you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Assume that you get to send only `2022-12-31` from your client, parsing it into a date in Java is very easy:

```
    String dateString = "2022-12-31";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Date parsed to: " + date);
```

Output:

> Date parsed to: 2022-12-31

`LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so what I think you need here. It parses the format `2022-12-31` natively and without any explicit formatter. The format is known as ISO 8601.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: +1 on the Java part.  For the JavaScript, you first get the current timestamp with `const d = new Date();` (really an instant, like `java.util.Date`), and then you can do either something like `\`${d.getFullYear()}-${(d.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}\`` or you can rely on that `en-CA` uses the ISO format already and do `d.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')`